# Sum of series: a^0+2a^1 + 3*a^2 + 4*a^3 + … + n*a^(n-1) (mod M)

Tags: c++, algorithm, number-theory

Can someone give me an idea of an efficient algorithm for large n which perform O(log(n)) using recursive function not geometric summation formula.

Comment: I can even give you `O(1)`: this is a sum of geometric sequence mod M.

Comment: @freakish well it is not constant complexity as you still need to compute `a^(n+1) ` which cannot be done in constant time

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev But `a^(n+1) mod M` can be computed in constant time.

Comment: @freakish how? You could use exponentiation by squaring like I suggest in my answer but this is not constant time.

Comment: @ashraful_haque stack overflow is not here to write code for you. However we can suggest an approach that would work. You will still need to do the coding on your own

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Have a look at this: https://www.cse.buffalo.edu/srds2009/escs2009_submission_Gopal.pdf

Comment: @freakish it seems this algorithm has constant performance at the cost of additional memory and precomputation. This will not improve the performance if you need to do a single exponentiation

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I've never said it will increase performance. Always benchmark.

Comment: Does anybody knows why this question was downvoted and got 2 close flags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the formula for sum of geometric progression: `a^1 + a^2 + ... a^n = (a^(n+1) - 1) / (a - 1)`. Using [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) you can compute (a^(n+1) - 1) in O(log(n)). If M is prime dividing by (a - 1) is simply one more exponentiation - for any U coprime with a prime number p, `U^(-1) (mod p) = U^(p-2) (mod p)`. You can prove this using [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Comment: Well, you don't have to divide in `mod M`. Actually for a non-prime `M` this might be difficult. Calculating `a^(n+1) mod M` is enough. All other calculations can be performed in integers in constant-time and after that `mod M` again.

Comment: @freakish not true. It may be the case that (a^(n+1) - 1) = 3 (mod m) and (a - 1) = 2016 (mod m) (here of course 2016 is random number smaller than m)

Comment: My bad, you have to additionally take `a - 1 mod M`. Note that `a/b mod M == (a mod M)/(b mod M)` where `==` means "congruent". The equality is true only if the right side makes sense, i.e. when `b mod M != 0`. In this case as long as `a != 1 mod M` then you can simply calculate `(a^(n+1) - 1 mod M) / (a - 1 mod M) mod M`

Comment: The assumption that `a != 1 mod M` is a lot better then that `M` has to be prime.

Comment: @freakish this is not true again due to the same example. Consider 64 / 8 (mod 3).

Comment: What is not true? I don't get your example.

Comment: @freakish 64 = 1 (mod 3), 8 = 2 (mod 3), then how much is 64 / 8 (mod 3) using the (wrong) formula you suggest?

Comment: The formula is correct, it is `1/2 mod 3`. But now I see that it cannot be calculated in integers, you still need to calculate the inverse. My bad.

Comment: @freakish Yes i also known that It's no possible to calculate in (a/b)mod(m) when b and m are not co-prime.  Then I don't use sum of geometric sequence mod M. If you have the O(log(n)) algorithm please describe the idea.

Comment: @ashraful_haque what I describe is O(log(n)) algorithm and I bet it is the one meant by the person that gave the task

Comment: Thank you to all of you I got it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as you state *M < 10<sup>5</sup>*, you know that all numbers will need at most 16 bits, so provided being just a little cautious, you should not be bothered by precision questions.

Next, as *a<sup>n</sup>(mod M) = (a(mod M))<sup>n</sup>(mod M)*, you can also say *a<M<10<sup>5</sup>*

Next if you note u<sub>n</sub>=a<sup>0</sup>+a<sup>1</sup>...a<sup>n-1</sup> (mod M), you can use the following recursions:

- u<sub>2k</sub> = u<sub>k</sub>+a<sup>k</sup>u<sub>k</sub> (mod M)
- u<sub>k+1</sub> = u<sub>k</sub>+a<sup>k</sup> (mod M)
- u<sub>2k+1</sub> = u<sub>k+1</sub>+a<sup>k+1</sup>u<sub>k</sub> (mod M) = u<sub>k</sub>+a<sup>k</sup>+a*a<sup>k</sup>u<sub>k</sub> (mod M)

Given a number n, you will find about log<sub>2</sub>(n) numbers n, n/2, n/4, ..., 1 and using the above formulas, you can compute easily u<sub>n/2<sup>i</sup></sub> and a<sup>n/2<sup>i</sup></sup> knowing u<sub>n/2<sup>i+1</sup></sub> and a<sup>n/2<sup>i+1</sup></sup>

This algorythm may not be trivial to write (specifically do not forget the mod M operation do make sure not to have overflows) because of different tests, but it **is** O(log<sub>2</sub>(n))